# Makefile for cross compilation linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, makefile

I have been asked to port our product into another application.(our s/w is running on linux virtualbox)

I have got a directory of their interface files and also a example code on trying to configure their software/hardware. I see their interface files under the s/w directory. In the reference code directory, I see a makefile with the reference to their reference code.

Trying to run their reference code makefile. getting error that

```
make: *** No rule to make target `../    main.o" :(
```

Btw donot understand why `SIMUDIR = -I\..\custom_simcode\` this is done in the makefile ?
Also not much familiar with crosscompiler syntax !

```
ifndef CROSS_CC_PREFIX
  CROSS_CC_PREFIX=$(CROSS_COMPILE)
endif

PROGRAM = customer_sim

CC=$(CROSS_CC_PREFIX)gcc
LD=$(CROSS_CC_PREFIX)ld
RANLIB=$(CROSS_CC_PREFIX)corelib
CFLAGS= -g

all: $(PROGRAM)

## Include path
SIMUDIR = -I\..\custom_simcode\             
CUST_INT_INC = -I./../cust_Intf/DecHandler/inc \
             -I./../CCPU

LIBDIR = -L./../cust_Intf \
         -L./../cust_IntfApi

LIBS = -lpthread -customercif -customerapi

LDFLAGS= $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS)
SOURCE = ./../custom_simcode/main.c \
         ./../custom_simcode/custcode_primitives_init.c \
         ./../custom_simcode/custccp_primitives_init.c

CFLAGS += $(SIMUDIR) $(CUST_INT_INC) -DPRINT_IO_CONSOLE -UADAPT_CCPU_CUSTIF
OBJS =  $(SOURCE:.c=.o)

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: $(SIMUDIR)/main.c $(SIMUDIR) $(CUST_INT_INC)
    $(CC) -c -o /main.o $(SIMUDIR)/main.c


clean:
    -rm -f $(OBJS) $(OBJS) $(PROGRAM)
```

Comment: You could use some `chroot`-ed environment -with development tools inside.

Comment: That use of `SIMUDIR` makes no sense. You should talk to the author of the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Your $(OBJS) list dependencies for $(PROGRAMs) with directories included but your rule for main.o doesn't have same path.

It would be better to have a generic rule to compile C files like

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Then simply assign extra dependencies for each file like:

```
$(OBJS): $(SIMUDIR) $(CUST_INT_INC)
```